# Python replacement abbreviation in html file

Tags: python, loops, replace

The idea is to open a textual file that contains abbreviation and full word. 
Like table with 2 column and n rows.
Then open html file, strip html signs , search for abbreviations , replace them and save them in new text file.

-------------------------It should open in file:
RASPUKNUTI, raspuknutivi
topografski u slucaju reflektivni za svaki...

## code

```
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import codecs
    #--------------------------------unos podataka za pretrazivanje
    dat=open('citaj.txt',"r")
    bs4_objekt=BeautifulSoup(dat,"lxml",from_encoding="UTF-8")
    onlytext=bs4_objekt.text.strip()
    #
    z=open('zamijeni_kratice3.txt','r')
    text=z.read()
    lista_rijeci=text.split('\n')
    for rijec in lista_rijeci:
        odjeli=rijec.split("|")
        samotext=re.sub("\s({0})".format(odjeli[0]),"{0}".format(odjeli[1]),onlytext)
        #sm2=re.sub(r'\s(refl.)','reflektivni',samotext)
    z.close()
    with codecs.open('novi_HAZU.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(sm2)
    f.close()
```

The words in format does not work , and it does not show error. When i put replace for just one word , works fine:
    `#sm2=re.sub(r'\s(refl.)','reflektivni',samotext)`
 I'm spinning in a loop here. Any suggestions , ideas ?

01.02.2016.  19:26
My goal is to get something similar to python interpreter as opposed to current state in file: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9OXB.png) 
Or the closest i can get to original : [address](https://www.fsb.unizg.hr/usb_frontend/files/1449073122-0-hazu_2.htm)

Comment: Could you please give your variables and files meaningful English names.  This would make it easier for us to understand your code. By the way, I would just open the html-file and the file with the abbreviations with `f.open()`, iterate through each abbreviation and replace it using `str.replace()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that, your code does not keep the change after substitution. Please try:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
#--------------------------------unos podataka za pretrazivanje
dat=open('citaj.txt',"r")
bs4_objekt=BeautifulSoup(dat,"lxml",from_encoding="UTF-8")
onlytext=bs4_objekt.text #.strip()
#
z=open('zamijeni_kratice3.txt','r')
text=z.read()
lista_rijeci=text.split('\n')
for rijec in lista_rijeci:
    odjeli=rijec.split("|")
    onlytext=re.sub("({0})".format(odjeli[0]),"{0}".format(odjeli[1]),onlytext)
z.close()
with codecs.open('novi_HAZU.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(onlytext)
f.close()
```

Not sure if this fits your needs (I used copy/paste, and made two `<tr>` elements for illustration purpose):

[image]

Comment: Thank you , the format now works . But my goal was not to join lines together. This html file is like a dictionary .  RASPUKNUTIV-( that is main word) ,raspukneutrumtivi-(that is synonim). They should be in one line , like a Title. And "topografemininumko u slucaju refemininum. za svaki..." thats explanation and it should be like a special column under main word , sepparated.

Comment: @biGmazi: To get the exact output in your description, I used line join. The main word and its synonim are in one line, which is the same as in the html file. Still confused about the output format. Can you please illustrate further the expected format?

Comment: @biGmazi: Or, you can format the output file to whatever you like,  since the replacement is now okay.

Comment: @biGmazi: You need to try it out on real files. Btw: do you have that '|' in your real html file?

Comment: I did not see "|" in html file but | is separator between pattern and word that need to be replaced in file that is not html . It must exist in that form.

Comment: I found '|' in the sample html file `citaj.txt`.

Comment: True, it exists in html file.

Comment: Easy to remove the '|' by `replace('|', '')`